# Attribute atl not allowed on element img at this point

Tags: html, css, lightbox, image-gallery

I'm making an image gallery and when I tried to Validate the code it gave two errors in every image from the gallery. 
Attribute atl not allowed on element img at this point.

> An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain
>   conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text
>   alternatives for images.
>    This is the code I have/:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.thumbnailss {
 border-style: none;
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 padding-left: 4px;
 padding-right: 4px;
 padding-top: 4px;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.italic { font-style: italic; }
.small { font-size: 0.8em; }

/** LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/

.lightbox {
 /** Default lightbox to hidden */
 display: none;
 /** Position and style */
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.lightbox img {
 /** Pad the lightbox image */
 max-width: 90%;
 max-height: 80%;
 margin-top: 2%;
}

.lightbox:target {
 /** Remove default browser outline */
 outline: none;

 /** Unhide lightbox **/
 display: block;
}
```

```html
   <!-- thumbnail image wrapped in a link -->
  <a href="#img1">
    <img src=../images/night/night_thumbnails/night_thumbs_01.jpg" atl="Monument Valley" class="thumbnailss">
  </a>
  <!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
 <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <img src="../images/night/night_thumbnails/night_thumbs_01.jpg" atl="Monument Valley">
  </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atl` Attribute is wrong,`alt` Attribute is correct.

> Read More : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp

**Change :**

`atl` Attribute

**to**

`alt` Attribute